# Unknown or unsupported command 'install'

Tags: python, module, command, prompt

[Unknown or unsupported command 'install'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Rwqe.jpg)

I am trying to install python modules using pip but the error `Unknown or unsupported command 'install'` comes up. I don't know if there is an `install.exe` file that I removed from my environment path or not. I'm not sure what I did to break this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the exact command you used and the exact error you received?

Answer (score 0):

[I believe you need to run pip through python.](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/pip-python-package-manager)  Try `python -m pip install matplotlob`

Comment: I reinstalled python and made sure it was added to path, and ran command prompt as an administrator and this worked. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help! Please remember to accept the answer if it addresses your question, so future users know what worked. Good luck with your project!